# Alternatives to writing an ODBC driver

Tags: c++, odbc, driver

We are storing allot of time series data into our own proprietary "database". In the next version of our system we want to give our users a simple query mechanism to extract the raw data from the database (as a complement to the reports our system can create) by using standard tools.

I have looked at the possibility to write an ODBC driver, but it looks like quite a daunting task, especially when the use will be very simple select statements.

I would be grateful for any tips, ideas and/or recommendation of libraries, that could make this task a bit simpler.

Our platform is Windows and our dev. env. is visual studio 2010 (nativ C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [LINQ provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx).

Comment: have to look into that, the interface to the "database" is a RPC interface, never used that in C# before, I guess you implement the whole thing as a dll or com object that talks via RPC to the "database"

Comment: @RA: You would need a protocol to talk between your manager LINQ provider and your back end. I would use REST and this would also give me REST access to the back end. But I have to say, none of these brings the majority of commercial products *any* closer, since the vast majority require ODBC or OleDB access.

Comment: thanks for the input , will take a closer look at it, but as you say, this maybe more for advanced customers integrating data in their own systems, than the people we have in mind, that is equipped with Toad and a bit of SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to take a look at [OData](http://www.odata.org), exposing your data as an OData producer, you would then be able to allow your users to query it right away using the already available [consumers](http://www.odata.org/consumers), e.g. Linqpad.

Comment: Looks interesting but the SDK, only problem seems to be a .Net/java only SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what makes your customers happy. Easier than an writing ODBC driver would seem to provide a library function that can parse simple SQL selects and deliver the result in whatever form desired.

Comment: Yes, agree. But it looks like he wants ODBC to allow his customers to use standard tools: I.E. Crystal Reports to generate Reports against his proprietary database.